# tkmessagebox doesnt pop up when i clicked button for first time but pops up at second time

Tags: python

IN THE BELOW PROGRAM

tkmessagebox doesnt pop up when I first clicked the button create but works the second time.why is that and can anyone pls debug the problem 
created this gui with at-designer. and the error "-[QNSApplication _setup:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fdcd3f65f60"

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets 

from tkinter import messagebox

class Ui_MYSQL_CREATEDB(object):
    def createdb(self):
        import mysql.connector
        try: 
            mydb=mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost', user='root',passwd='logon@123',database='python')
            mycursor=mydb.cursor()  
            messagebox.showinfo(title='hello',message='hello')
        except Exception:
            messagebox.showerror('connection failed ')



    def setupUi(self, MYSQL_CREATEDB):
        MYSQL_CREATEDB.setObjectName("MYSQL_CREATEDB")
        MYSQL_CREATEDB.resize(406, 239)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(MYSQL_CREATEDB)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 10, 281, 81))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Comic Sans MS")
        font.setPointSize(24)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(MYSQL_CREATEDB)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 110, 171, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Comic Sans MS")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.btncreate = QtWidgets.QPushButton(MYSQL_CREATEDB)
        self.btncreate.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 160, 112, 32))
        self.btncreate.setObjectName("btncreate")
        self.btncreate.clicked.connect(self.createdb)
        self.btncancel = QtWidgets.QPushButton(MYSQL_CREATEDB)
        self.btncancel.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 160, 112, 32))
        self.btncancel.setObjectName("btncancel")
        self.txtDBname = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(MYSQL_CREATEDB)
        self.txtDBname.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(182, 110, 211, 31))
        self.txtDBname.setObjectName("txtDBname")
        self.txtDBname.raise_()
        self.label.raise_()
        self.label_2.raise_()
        self.btncreate.raise_()
        self.btncancel.raise_()

        self.retranslateUi(MYSQL_CREATEDB)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MYSQL_CREATEDB)

    def retranslateUi(self, MYSQL_CREATEDB):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MYSQL_CREATEDB.setWindowTitle(_translate("MYSQL_CREATEDB", "Form"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MYSQL_CREATEDB", "CREATING DATABASE"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MYSQL_CREATEDB", "DATABASE NAME: "))
        self.btncreate.setText(_translate("MYSQL_CREATEDB", "CREATE"))
        self.btncancel.setText(_translate("MYSQL_CREATEDB", "CANCEL"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MYSQL_CREATEDB = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_MYSQL_CREATEDB()
    ui.setupUi(MYSQL_CREATEDB)
    MYSQL_CREATEDB.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Mixing two entirely different GUI toolkits seems like a recipe for disaster.  Surely PyQT has some sort of message box of its own?

Comment: i think problem is using tkinter messagebox with pyqt instead why dont you use pyqt message box . https://www.tutorialspoint.com/pyqt/pyqt_qmessagebox.htm

Comment: Ohk.got it.Thanks for the reasoning